# How to update a windows service without having to uninstall service from service list

Tags: c#, windows, service

So I'm trying to figure out how to stop a service, update the code and then start the service again. I'm stopping the service with this:

sc stop "name of service"

When I update the code (override the exe file and additional reference files) and try to restart the service like this--sc start "name of service"--it tells me this:

[SC] StartService FAILED 1053:

The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

If I put the original files back and try to restart the service it starts fine.

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Presumably the new version fails and throws an exception; look in the event viewer. Add logging/tracing/debug it

Comment: you were right.  I screwed up and by fixing my start process it worked fine.